# FreeRADIUS using Active Directory integration broken without any traces

Tags: freebsd, ntlm, freeradius, samba4, winbind

I've a FreeBSD 10.0 server running FreeRADIUS 3 and things got broken without any apparent reason.

I'm using Winbind from Samba4 to authenticate with `ntlm_auth`. I've done some debug to solve the problem, but I was unable to find where is the problem.

`ntlm_auth` is working:

```
ntlm_auth --username=ferrao --request-nt-key
Password: 
NT_STATUS_OK: Success (0x0)
```

But RADIUS fails when doing EAP-PEAP authentication, and running FreeRADIUS in debug mode this is the error message:

```
(9) mschap : Executing: /usr/local/bin/ntlm_auth --request-nt-key --username=%{%{Stripped-User-Name}:-%{%{User-Name}:-None}} --challenge=%{%{mschap:Challenge}:-00} --nt-response=%{%{mschap:NT-Response}:-00}
(9) mschap : EXPAND --username=%{%{Stripped-User-Name}:-%{%{User-Name}:-None}}
(9) mschap :    --> --username=ferrao
(9) mschap : Creating challenge hash with username: ferrao
(9) mschap : EXPAND --challenge=%{%{mschap:Challenge}:-00}
(9) mschap :    --> --challenge=082e8ba7b848aaae
(9) mschap : EXPAND --nt-response=%{%{mschap:NT-Response}:-00}
(9) mschap :    --> --nt-response=27b40a6d1dba1b4acfd33aff5c710a43e70d050269087bf1
(9) ERROR: mschap : Program returned code (1) and output 'Reading winbind reply failed! (0xc0000001)'
(9) mschap : External script failed.
(9) ERROR: mschap : External script says: Reading winbind reply failed! (0xc0000001)
(9) ERROR: mschap : MS-CHAP2-Response is incorrect
(9)   [mschap] = reject
(9)  } # Auth-Type MS-CHAP = reject
(9) eap : Freeing handler
(9)   [eap] = reject
(9)  } #  authenticate = reject
(9) Failed to authenticate the user.
(9) Login incorrect (mschap: Program returned code (1) and output 'Reading winbind reply failed! (0xc0000001)'): [ferrao/<via Auth-Type = EAP>] (from client 146.164.136.0/26 port 0 via TLS tunnel)
```

So something is wrong with Winbind and FreeRADIUS, and I don't know what.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Which version specifically of FreeRADIUS?

Comment: freeradius3-3.0.3_5

Answer (score 3):

Check the permissions of the winbind privileged pipe - the user that FreeRADIUS runs as needs to be able to access it. You probably need to add your FreeRADIUS user into the `winbindd_priv` group, and then make sure that the privileged pipe is owned by root:winbindd_priv.

The winbind privileged pipe is usually in `/var/lib/samba/winbindd_privileged/`, or a similar location under /var/.